# disable function name in across || dplyr || summarise

Tags: r, dplyr, across

```
iris %>%  group_by(Species) %>% summarise(across( .cols = is.numeric, .fns = list(Sum = sum), na.rm = TRUE))
```

I'm grouping rows by species and them adding their values per column which are numeric.

Output looks like:

`summarise() ungrouping output (override with .groups argument)`
`Species    Sepal.Length_Sum Sepal.Width_Sum Petal.Length_Sum Petal.Width_Sum`
`<fct>                 <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>`
`setosa                 250.            171.             73.1            12.3`
`versicolor             297.            138.            213              66.3`
`virginica              329.            149.            278.            101.`

I'd like to remove **_Sum** that is added after across function is applied.

R 4.0.0
dplyr 1.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need a named `list` in that case

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(across( .cols = is.numeric, .fns = sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or if we still wanted to use a named `list`, then specify the `.names` which would give more control in adding prefix or suffix as well as removing anything extra by specifying only `{col}`

```
iris %>%  
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(across( .cols = is.numeric, .fns = list(Sum = sum), 
            .names = "{col}",na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 setosa             250.        171.         73.1        12.3
#2 versicolor         297.        138.        213          66.3
#3 virginica          329.        149.        278.        101.
```